# How do you pass parameters to called function using ASP.Net Ajax $addHandler

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I am trying to use the $addHandler function to add a handler to a text box's click event

```
var o=$get('myTextBox');
var f = Type.parse('funcWithArgs');
$addHandler(o, 'click', f);
```

However I need to pass parameters to the called function. How do you do that?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your function with an anonymous function (aka lambda):

```
$addHandler(o, 'click', function() { f(my, arguments, go, here); });
```

---

#### Alternative solution:

If you had a function that created partials, you could do that as well - I use a toolkit that provides for that, and this is how it would be done:

```
$addHandler(o, 'click', partial(f, my, arguments, go, here));
```

I don't know (and actually doubt) that Microsoft's framework provides for that, but you could look into writing your own `partial` function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I keep forgetting the hidden powers of JavaScript.

Comment: No problem - I have been earnestly hacking JavaScript for about 3.5 years now and love it to death. I am always amazed at how powerful it is and love showing people that think it is a joke just how much you can do with it. Not that it is perfect!

Comment: Oh, and just make sure you are careful about closures when you set that up...it can come back to bite you unless you understand what those are...

Comment: Can you point me to an article/blog post that can help me better understand closures and their implications? - Thanks

Comment: Well, try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work